# Why do I receive a timeout error from Pythons requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

I use `requests.post(url, headers, timeout=10)` and sometimes I received a `ReadTimeout exception HTTPSConnectionPool(host='domain.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)`

Since I already set timeout as 10 seconds, why am I still receiving a ReadTimeout exception?

Comment: Wrap it in a try/catch block?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Per https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts, that is the expected behavior.  As royhowie mentioned, wrap it in a try/except block
(e.g.:

```
try:
  requests.post(url, headers, timeout=10)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
  print "Timeout occurred"
```

)

Comment: hi tk u for quick reply. this is a better answer because Catching this error will catch both ConnectTimeout and ReadTimeout errors.

Comment: @nuttynibbles You said in your question how to catch `ReadTimeout exception?`. Otherwise just only use `try/except` and catch all of them.

Comment: sorry i am not sure why it is showing 0 vote here even though i upvote your ans

Comment: hi @howaboutNO, initially i thought by putting the timeout argument, it will auto stop the requests process if it takes longer than that

Comment: Using this answer, I wrote a function to deal with it: https://hastebin.com/izaponomer.py

Comment: This is great, however, how to continue in the loop?
I am going through a page several times and record the response time in a loop and use try and except. But I would like it to go to the next run once a timeout occured.

Answer (score 10):

```
try:
    #defined request goes here
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    # Set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop
```

You can wrap it like an exception block like this. Since you asked for this only `ReadTimeout`. Otherwise catch all of them;

```
try:
    #defined request goes here
except:
    # Set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop
```

Comment: hi tk you for quick reply. i shall do that

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can try is at the end of your code block, include the following:

```
time.sleep(2)
```

This worked for me. The delay is longer (in seconds) but might help overcome the issue you're having.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `time.sleep()` for something like this as  suspends the thread that it is invoked from. Increasing the timeout is more viable in this case.